# How to send USD to Transferwise EUR balance?

Tags: united-states, international-transfer, swift

I have a Transferwise account that only has bank details for EUR. I gave all the account details to my client in USA so they can do the transfer.

Unfortunately my client replied that they won't be able to do the transfer unless I provide an intermediary bank. Transferwise told me they can't provide that information and Bank of America seems to be unable to do the transfer without that.

I'm surprised they can't use their own intermediary banks...

Is an intermediary bank something I could just find myself? Is there any other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, correspondent banks are automatically filled by the sending bank, unless there is restriction on the usage of such correspondent bank accounts. End-Users/Customers can't really locate the correspondent bank and account numbers on thier own.

I suggest that you obtain a [USD Transferwise Account](https://transferwise.com/help/17/borderless-account/2827506/how-do-i-use-my-usd-bank-details) so that your client sends USD to USD via Fedwire/ACH system and avoid SWIFT entirely. Then you can perform currency conversion within the Transferwise website/App to move USD into EUR.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatelly I cannot have a USD balance with bank details in my country, only EUR :(